# SQL between higher and lower number

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I'm trying to return values where a column number is between '2000' and '500'.
when i do equals 2000 i get the returned row, however when i do it as between i return no rows...

This is my query...

```
SELECT * FROM PRE_ADVICE_LINE WHERE (PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1 BETWEEN '2100' AND '500')
```

I'm not sure if i can return rows where the between values goes from higher to lower values. I've also tried the SQL as this too:

```
SELECT * FROM PRE_ADVICE_LINE WHERE (PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1 BETWEEN 2100 AND 500)
```

I feel it's an obvious error on my behalf, but i cannot fathom it!

Comment: Do **not** compare numbers to strings

Comment: A `BETWEEN` condition determines whether the value of one expression is in an interval defined by two other expressions. Eg: `expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3`, and `expr2` and `expr3` should be in increasing order, otherwise the result will be NULL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, we can compare number with strings, because in `BETWEEN` clause If the expressions are not all the same datatype, then Oracle Database implicitly converts the expressions to a common datatype.

Comment: Your condition `WHERE user_def_num_1 BETWEEN '2100' AND '500'` would work. It would return rows with values '2200', '23', '3ABC' and so on. The comparision looks at one letter after the other. Your column `user_def_num_1`, however, seems to be numeric. So Oracle turns your strings implicitely into numbers: `WHERE user_def_num_1 BETWEEN TO_NUMBER('2100') AND TO_NUMBER('500')` i.e. `WHERE user_def_num_1 BETWEEN 2100 AND 500`. In `BETWEEN` the order of the elements matters. It translates to `WHERE user_def_num_1 >= 2100 AND user_def_num_1 <= 500` which is never true.

Comment: @ihm017: relying on implicit data type conversion is a really, really bad idea to begin with. Do not get used to that. Anywhere you do that you are creating a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: yes agreed @a_horse_with_no_name .. i was just mentioning that it can be done, though it should not be done.

Answer (score 4):

Values for `BETWEEN` need to be in order.  If you have a number, then don't use single quotes

What you want would seem to be:

```
WHERE PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1 BETWEEN 500 AND 2100
```

Answer (score 1):

use between properly below way

```
   SELECT * FROM PRE_ADVICE_LINE
 WHERE  PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1 BETWEEN 500 AND 2100
```

or you can use

```
SELECT * FROM PRE_ADVICE_LINE
   WHERE  PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1>=500
   AND   PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1<=2100
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
 SELECT * FROM PRE_ADVICE_LINE WHERE PRE_ADVICE_LINE.USER_DEF_NUM_1 BETWEEN 500 AND 2100;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a far more useful answer if you provided some explanation as to how it answers the question (i.e. what was wrong originally and what has changed to make it work)